# Warning: Attempt to read past end of file in SGETTOK Prolog abort

Tags: prolog

I was trying to do `consult(file_name)` when i get the following error -

> "Warning: Attempted to read past end of file
>
> Warning: Attempt to read past end of file in SGETTOK
> Prolog abort."

This happens for every program I run.

Comment: Do you mean for every program you *consult*, correct? I guess "SGETTOK" is an abbreviation for a stream get token operation? Which Prolog system are you using?

Comment: What do you mean, *happens for every program I run*? Do you mean `file_name` represents your program? Can you show *exactly* how you typed the `consult(file_name)` and what the file name was? And check the file contents that you have properly formed Prolog. The error looks like the syntax was expecting another token, but you didn't provide it, indicating a syntax error in that file somewhere. Try a `file_name` with much simpler contents and, if that gives the same error, show us what the file contents are.